# Core Plot Automatic Labelling Policy

Tags: ios, core-plot

Using the Axis Labelling Policy Automatic works fine but sometimes the last value is not included in the labels.So if on X-axis labels are from 0 to 3800;using automatic labelling policy the labels do appear at interval of 500 from 0 to 3500. Is there any way by which I can add the last label (here 3800) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the automatic labeling policy. There's no easy way to determine automatically if that last label would fit without overlapping the one next to it. You might want to try a different labeling policy. If you always want the first and last values labeled, use the equal divisions policy. Otherwise, try the fixed interval policy (the default), or use custom labels if you don't care about equal spacing between the labels.

Comment: But without using the Automatic Labelling Policy the labels won't adjust themselves when the graph is zoomed, right ? So is there any way to include this as well if we are using a different labelling policy.

Comment: They will, but the labeling depends on the policy in use. If you want total control, use custom labels and monitor changes to the plot space with a plot space delegate. Update the labels and ticks as needed when the plot space changes.